# How can I acces to a cookie from another folder?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm a rookie programming php, maybe my question is too simple, I do not know.

I am developing a project with the following structure

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXfn.jpg)

In the control file I am creating two cookies with the information entered by the user in login.php form with the sentences:

```
if(isset($_POST["remenber"])){
   setcookie("email",$_POST["email"]);
   setcookie("password",$_POST["password"]);

}
```

I have checked with the browser that the cookies are created and they are.

I want to recover the information of the user of the cookies, the next time he accesses the login, I'm trying with the following codes but I don't have access to the cookies

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["email"])){ echo $_COOKIE["email"];}?>
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])){ echo $_COOKIE["password"];}?>
```

How can I access cookies in login.php?

Comment: `I'm a rookie` am I the only one to notice the humor here.  A "rookie" dealing with "cookies"  lmao.  {smile becomes a frown} However this is really bad idea `setcookie("password",$_POST["password"])`  for security reasons you should never store the password in plantext, and never ever put it in a cookie.

Comment: Are you tring to make something like  a "Remember Me" type of system, or what is the purpose of this?  Basically your users expect their passwords would be protected.  What if they use the same password for their banking (bad idea but it happens).  Now you have just stored the plantext password in their browser.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want to do, a remember me system.
Obviously I know it's not safe to save passwords in cookies

Comment: There are several good ways to do that, but it's probably beyond the scope of this site to explain it.  However I can post something that highlights the features it should have.  Essentially it's to much for me to code in depth and post here.